# adding user input to python code - sha1 code

Tags: python, python-2.7

The below code from https://gist.github.com/bonsaiviking/5639034

is a sha1 hashing code, but I'd like to be able to input a text message for it to hash. And I just don't see where (which variable) the message is supposed to be input, or if I need to first call the functions as I need them. I'm a little unfamiliar with python classes. I understand what the code is doing, however the `self` part of it confuses me. i have read up on classes and the python `self` but am still confused about it.

Could someone please guide me in the right direction on how to input a message to be hashed in the below code. thanks

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import struct

def leftrotate(i, n):
    return ((i << n) & 0xffffffff) | (i >> (32 - n))

class SHA1(object):
    def __init__(self, data=""):
        self.h = [
                0x67452301,
                0xEFCDAB89,
                0x98BADCFE,
                0x10325476,
                0xC3D2E1F0
                ]
        self.remainder = data
        self.count = 0

    def _add_chunk(self, chunk):
        self.count += 1
        w = list( struct.unpack(">16I", chunk) + (None,) * (80-16) )
        for i in xrange(16, 80):
            n = w[i-3] ^ w[i-8] ^ w[i-14] ^ w[i-16]
            w[i] = leftrotate(n, 1)
        a,b,c,d,e = self.h
        for i in xrange(80):
            f = None
            k = None
            if i < 20:
                f = (b & c) ^ (~b & d)
                k = 0x5A827999
            elif i < 40:
                f = b ^ c ^ d
                k = 0x6ED9EBA1
            elif i < 60:
                f = (b & c) ^ (b & d) ^ (c & d)
                k = 0x8F1BBCDC
            else:
                f = b ^ c ^ d
                k = 0xCA62C1D6

            temp = (leftrotate(a,5) + f + e + k + w[i]) % 2**32
            e = d
            d = c
            c = leftrotate(b, 30)
            b = a
            a = temp
        self.h[0] = (self.h[0] + a) % 2**32
        self.h[1] = (self.h[1] + b) % 2**32
        self.h[2] = (self.h[2] + c) % 2**32
        self.h[3] = (self.h[3] + d) % 2**32
        self.h[4] = (self.h[4] + e) % 2**32

    def add(self, data):
        message = self.remainder + data
        r = len(message) % 64
        if r != 0:
            self.remainder = message[-r:]
        else:
            self.remainder = ""
        for chunk in xrange(0, len(message)-r, 64):
            self._add_chunk(message[chunk:chunk+64])
        return self

    def finish(self):
        l = len(self.remainder) + 64 * self.count
        self.add( "\x80" + "\x00" * ((55 - l) % 64) + struct.pack(">Q", l * 8) )
        h = tuple(x for x in self.h)
        self.__init__()
        return struct.pack(">5I", *h)
```

Comment: Sorry for the question, but why not using sha1 implementation from hashlib module? Writing your own cryptographic hash function in usually not the best idea

Comment: learning purposes. understanding the cryptographic routines from scratch. Hashlib is too easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to concern yourself with `self` unless you're writing code *within* the class. Using the SHA1 class is as easy as

```
data= raw_input('Enter text to hash: ')
sha= SHA1(data)
print 'SHA-1 hash:', sha.finish()
```

Or, to make use of the `.add` function:

```
sha= SHA1()
data= raw_input('Enter text to hash: ')
sha.add(data)
print 'SHA-1 hash:', sha.finish()
```

---

To elaborate on `self`: Functions that are defined within a class need an instance of that class to operate on. This instance is passed to the function as its first parameter and is usually called `self`. (If you're familiar with other programming languages, `self` is the python equivalent of `this`.) The `self` parameter is passed automatically if you call a function as `instance.function()` (for example `sha.finish()`), so it's almost like it's not even there. You only need to concern yourself with it if you're writing a function for a class.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that, i've tried to hash a word now and it outputs as `*�l5�Oϴ��_@����F` 
do i need to output it in Hexadecimal or base64?

Comment: And thanks for the `self` explanation. it does make it clearer. i think it confused me because i wasn't sure if i could call the class like you did in the example above, or that it would work the same way.

Comment: @LewisFletch: You need hex. You can use `''.join('%02x'%ord(c) for c in sha.finish())` to get the hex representation.

Comment: ahh awesome, yep i know the code, i've used it in a previous implementation of an RC4 Cipher, thanks for your help. marking it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
def add(self, data):
```

Look out under this function. I think the massage goes trough here. İsn't that your question ?

About your second question, yes you need to call the functions you need or just the general function.

After this code you can call the add(1,2) function put veriables I hope it works

I think the other problem is your definitions is not in the class so thats why when you call class it won't give you result. Try to put def's in class and let me now if it works

Comment: Hrmrmr, possibly. i did see this before but it doesn't call the function `finish` at all.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M1BAlDufqao in this tutorial it covers classes and self. I trying to understand why finish doesn't work. I am also new at programming but searching for answers now :)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [test.py](https://github.com/ajalt/python-sha1/blob/master/test.py):

```
   `msg = bytearray(get_random_bytes())
    first_digest = sha1.sha1(bytes(msg))
    second_digest = sha1.sha1(bytes(msg))`
```

`data` in sha1.py probably is the input I guess.